# Pandas: Crash when dividing one column by the other with index set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a larger data set, with *121232* rows and many columns:

```
           a      b        c
year                                                                   
1983     722   1001  1.06300  
1984     722   1001  1.24225
```

If I do

```
df['new'] = df['a']/df['b']
```

pandas, python, my editor (PyCharm) and Windows 7 all together crash, one after the other. I guess there is an additional issue related to PyCharm and its memory usage, but this should not be happening inside pandas in the first place, should it?

By the way, if I reset the index before the division, `pandas` does not crash.

My pandas version is `0.13.1`. My Python system: `2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:30:12) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)`

Comment: How many rows and are you using 64-bit python?

Comment: This worked fine for me using ipython 2.0 python 3.3 64-bit pandas 0.13.1, maybe a problem with pycharm, I have 16gb on my machine but I don't think that should make a difference as your dataset size is small. Not sure why resetting the index would suddenly make it work